# Why would localhost cookies in Chrome stop working?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies, localhost, chromium

I have an ASP.NET project running on localhost. There's a page **admin/LoginAsEmployee.aspx** - it sets 3 cookies (called "FedAuth", "FedAuth1" and another one), and redirects to a 2nd page, **Home.aspx**.

That 2nd page has always been able to access these 3 cookies... But some time ago it stopped working (a few days/weeks, not sure exactly). **Home.aspx** does not see the cookies!

It works fine in the Edge browser, I can only repro the problem in Chrome.

Here's what I see in the 1st request, cookies are set correctly:
[image]

And here's the 2nd request, happens milliseconds after the 1st request, cookies are definitely not expired, yet Chrome does not send them back:
[image]

What could be going wrong here? Why would it break all of a sudden? Could it be related to some recent Chrome update? Is there a known Chrome bug number for this?